# ImportError: No module named Courses.wsgi

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework, gunicorn, digital-ocean

I have a problem with gunicorn binding. Now I am firstly using this tool. And have this error message:

I tried to run `gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 Courses.wsgi`

> ImportError: No module named Courses.wsgi

Import is correctly from my working directory? If it's not correct, please help me with them. Thanks all in advance.

Here the structure of my working directories:

courses_api

Courses

├── manage.py

Courses

├── urls.py

├── settings.py

├── wsgi.py

├── init.py

settings.py:

```
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'Courses.wsgi.application'
```

wsgi.py:

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "Courses.settings")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow below steps before running `gunicorn`

1. change directory

```
$ cd /home/don1k/courses_api/Courses/
```

2. Run `gunicorn` command

```
$ gunicorn --pythonpath /home/ubuntu/courses_api/env,/home/don1k/courses_api/Courses --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 Courses.wsgi
```

Reference: http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/settings.html#pythonpath

Comment: File "/home/don1k/courses_api/Courses/Courses/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
    from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi - It's showed the same error(

Comment: @DanilPopov try using `--pythonpath` as your virtual environment so that it ca use `django` package.

Comment: I also tried it, but it gives me error's message:  File "/home/don1k/courses_api/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
    __import__(module)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Courses.wsgi'

Comment: @DanilPopov Updated the answer. Please check it.